# puppeteer launch is not capturing screen shots in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I am launching puppeteer to take a screen shot of a browser. This is my code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(filePath);
    await page.screenshot({ 
      path: outputPath,
      type: "png",
      fullPage: true,
      omitBackground: true
});
  
await browser.close();
```

But it is not working
I have tried this also

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
 });
```

but the second one is working on live environment but not in local.
both were working few days back on local.
Can somebody help me out ?

Comment: When you say "it is not working" may you be more specific? Is there an error?

Comment: there is no error. The code executes without any errors.